# How can I add an active state to this jQuery code

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation

Any opinion, how to add an active state (which remains highlighted after selected) to this code?

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul#navigation span").css("opacity","0");
    $("ul#navigation span").hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, "slow");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a css class to the item when you select the item.

the .addClass() jQuery method will do this.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i'm new to this jQuery thing. can you explain?

Comment: The addClass() and removeClass() methods in jQuery, by adding a CSS class to a defined object (say, `jQuery(this).addClass('selected')` ), let you add a kind of state to a page or objects on that page.

What are you trying to do here?

Comment: well, this is what i need with an active state: http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/animated-menus-using-jquery/

Comment: Then the following should work for you: `$('ul#navigation span').click(function(){ $(this).toggleClass('active');});` and then write a CSS rule in your stylesheet to control the appearance. Change the 'click' part to be whatever function you need the change to occur on.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your looking for, but this could be done in a number of ways depending on your specific use?

Here's a fiddle to show how it's usually done with classes : http://jsfiddle.net/zqTLu/5/

Comment: thank you so much adeneo! and what if a sprite pic used as menu elements, not css red-green colours?

Comment: the only problem is that i must click again to the same item to removeve active state... i mean, if i click another item, then the previous item change back to no active. how should i modify the code?

Comment: Just remove the active class from all span elements before attaching the active class again to the clicked span element, see [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zqTLu/12/) for an explanation.

Comment: thanks, it's works fine. one more thing left: what if i like the removeClass is animated too? it's not just remove but animate out (fade).